# upright piano and apartment: how to prevent neighborhood problems?

Tags: piano, noise

I am dealing a K-200 because I liked this piano very much. But I am concerned about possible problems with my neighborhood. Here’s my detailed setup: I live in a concrete apartment, my floor is in porcelanate (original was ceramic, I just put porcelanate over the old ceramic floor), highest floor (10th, nobody lives above me, there’s a playground/party hall above me specifically), the apartment right below me (9th) is vacant as is the one below it (8th)(the owners only come in specific holidays, since my town is good for tourism), the bedroom in which the piano will stay have no direct sharing walls with neighborhood (my apartment is in the corner and this bedroom is exactly the corner of the building. So the 4 walls are: behind the piano (front of the player): outside; left of the player: outside with a window; back of the player: my main bedroom wall, and right: my social toilet. Can you visualize?). There are no near buildings near my building - I can see the clean horizon from all my windows. However, there are 6 apartments per floor and I am worried about possible problems with collateral neighbors. There is a window in this bedroom that will be only 2 meters away from the piano (I will triple-glass soundproof it). The bedroom is small, 3x3 meters. The main door of the apartment is in the opposite extreme of the piano and there are 2 doors before it, so I’m not worried about corridor noise (I will further wind seal these doors anyway). What are my chances of problem here? Will the sound propagate to many floors below me, or to other units? What do you suggest?

My plan was making a decoupling that is just described as the following, from piano to ground order: rubber washing machine feet, decorative thin rug, MDF, thick rug, rubber mattress (a rug for kids playing over it), thick rug again and ground, so MDF spreads the pressure evenly through the sandwich. Moving away the piano from the back wall 25cm, dense eggcrate foam with points towards the soundboard, between the foam and the wall, a layer of dense rock wool glued or fixed in the wall somehow.

What are approximately my chances of success? Im losing my hopes and giving up an upright piano =( but I am simply not buying another digital piano...

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

I recently used a pvc foam adhesive tape to seal all my doors, and a set of 2 rolls of hard foam that is sold with this purpose, to seal the gap below the doors. My TV has 60" and is only 20cm away laterally from my main door of my apartment, i just set the volume of the TV to maximum (about 90 dB I think) and then I went to the corridor and shut the door, the sound was audible but like a soft whisper, almost hard to recognize the words. Airborne sound is easy to control and for me this part is done already (there is another door between this door and my piano, and this second door is sealed as well, so...). The piano dealer will let me test it for a week, the piano arrives tomorrow, if problems occur he will let me return the piano at no cost. I said rubber mattress up there, but it’s actually an EVA mattress with about 1,5cm of width. Unfortunately some people marked this as duplicate, but I think every case is unique, as is the relationship of walls of my neighborhood with my apartment. Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with sound transmission from acoustic pianos is through the floor into the building structure. Since the piano is heavy, this is hard to eliminate.

I would start by getting some proper polyurethane sound-absorbing caster cups. Don't try to improvise - a set of 4 for an upright will probably cost about $100, which is cheap compared with the cost of the piano.

If that isn't sufficient, you can either soundproof the walls, or put sound absorbing material onto or inside the piano itself. But normally two sets of closed windows (in your apartment and the other one) will block out all the airborne sound transmission.

For doors and corridor noise, the important thing is to avoid any gaps around the door - fill them with draught excluder tape or something similar.

If none of that works, the only real solution is a false floor that doesn't transmit sound to the building floor - but that will be expensive!